# CSS error in stylesheet

Tags: css

Hello i have this wordpress template that i got from someone, however i noticed that there are some errors in the style sheet file, i found this line in that file:

```
ul.gdlr-twitter-widget li:before{ font-size: 25px; line-height: 24px; float: left; margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px; font-family: FontAwesome; 
    content: '\f099'; *zoom:expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xf099;'); }
```

Now this line is underlined in red in my IDE:

```
expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xf099;');
```

I'm average in CSS not really an expert so i am finding it difficult understanding what the above code does and how to fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191679/css-expressions)

Comment: Your expression should return a number or a percentage, not 2 javascript actions. So expression(0.5 + 0.5) is good but expression(doSomething, doSomething) is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an IE 7 hack to emulate the the `content` property of the `:before` pseudo-element, because `content` is not supported before IE 8. If you don't care about IE 7, you can just remove this bit:

```
*zoom:expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xf099;');
```

because all modern browsers will ignore that and pay attention to `content: '\f099'`, which does the same thing, but properly.

If you *do* care about IE 7, you should probably just ignore the error.

More info: [Can CSS Content Property work in IE7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157625/can-css-content-property-work-in-ie7/11577520#11577520)